# Writing a function to draw a rounded rectangle with optional sides (same as CSS)?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-path

I'm trying to draw a path for a rounded rectangle where the sides are optional but having some difficulties. I've found and been shown similar questions but those functions ask for existing path data. I'm starting from scratch.

The function would look like this:

```
function drawRoundRect(width, height, sides, topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius) {
    pathData = "";
    return pathData;
}
```

If I knew how to do this I wouldn't be asking here.

The user would be able to say:

```
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top left right", 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

and it would create a rectangle with three sides where the bottom line of the rectangle is not drawn.

Or for a full rectangle they would write this:

```
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top left right bottom", 10, 10, 10, 10);

// top and bottom no rounded corners
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top bottom", 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add x and y arguments to your function's argument list so you know the position of the rectangle.

You will need to make a design choice on when corners are drawn. Are corners when at least one of the adjacent sides are drawn? Or are corners only drawn when both adjacent sides are drawn?

You will need to break the path up into eight sections: four lines (one for each side) and four arcs (one for each corner). This will require you to calculate two points per side (i.e. end points of line for each size). Then go around the rectangle, adding or skipping each of the sections to your path data. Use line commands (L|l|H|h|V|v) to add line sections. Use arc commands (A|a) to add arc sections. Use move commands (M|m) to skip sections.